# How to use move to with feelings

Tags: word-usage

How do I use "move to" with feelings?

According to the definition of "move to" for feelings on the Cambridge dictionary website, we can use it to:
"to cause someone to have strong feelings, such as sadness, sympathy, happiness, or admiration"

but can I say for example since they didn't use it as an example:

> 1 She was moved to happiness.

or

> 2 She was moved to sadness.

Comment: 'Moved to tears' is the most common usage (when a situation makes someone feel such strong emotion that they want to cry).

Answer (score 2):

I think "moved to" works better with immediate responses, or with actions, rather than with persistent states like happiness and sadness.
These work well:
moved to tears
moved to sympathy
moved to act
moved to respond

Here is a link to Google ngram viewer showing that "moved to tears" is 250 times more likely than "moved to happiness":
[Google ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moved%20to%20tears%2Cmoved%20to%20happiness&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmoved%20to%20tears%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoved%20to%20happiness%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmoved%20to%20tears%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmoved%20to%20happiness%3B%2Cc0)